# How to define irregular-shaped sprites inside a Cocos2D physics world

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I'd like to create sprites out of the 26 English characters and let them collide with each other inside a frame (for example, like X and E in diagram below).

[image]

What's the recommended way to create the 26 shapes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You take 26 image Sprite for each character of the alphabet (.png image will be prefered), then define the fixture of each character, (with the help of vertexHelper Refer [THIS](http://www.springenwerk.com/2010/02/introducing-vertexhelper-for-box2d.html) Link for knowing more about **vertextHelper**), like for 'I' it will be:

```
 //OBSTACLE_Adjustments
    {
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"I.png"];
        sprite.position = ccp(96,96);
        sprite.tag = 2;
        [self addChild:sprite];

        //SHAPE 1:
        {
            b2BodyDef bodyDefinition;
            bodyDefinition.type = b2_dynamicBody;
            bodyDefinition.position.Set(96/PTM_RATIO, 96/PTM_RATIO);
            bodyDefinition.userData = sprite;

            obstacle_AdjustmentsBody= world->CreateBody(&bodyDefinition);

            // Create body shape
            b2PolygonShape bodyShape;
            //row 1, col 1
            int num = 4;
            b2Vec2 verts[] = {
                b2Vec2(6.5f / PTM_RATIO, -25.0f / PTM_RATIO),
                b2Vec2(6.5f / PTM_RATIO, 27.0f / PTM_RATIO),
                b2Vec2(-7.5f / PTM_RATIO, 27.0f / PTM_RATIO),
                b2Vec2(-7.5f / PTM_RATIO, -26.0f / PTM_RATIO)
            };

            bodyShape.Set(verts, num);

            // Create shape definition and add to body
            b2FixtureDef bodyFixtureDefinition;
            bodyFixtureDefinition.shape = &bodyShape;
            bodyFixtureDefinition.density = 100.0f;
            bodyFixtureDefinition.friction = 0.01f;
            bodyFixtureDefinition.restitution = 0.50f;              
            obstacle_AdjustmentsFixture=obstacle_AdjustmentsBody->CreateFixture(&bodyFixtureDefinition);            
        }
}
```

here `obstacle_AdjustmentsBody` is `b2Body`, and `obstacle_AdjustmentsFixture` is `b2Fixture`.

**HERE IS SHAPE FOR X:**

```
 //OBSTACLE_ALPHABATE
    {
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"X.png"];
        sprite.position = ccp(96,96);
        sprite.tag = 2;
        [self addChild:sprite];

        //SHAPE FIRST LEG OF X:
        {
            b2BodyDef bodyDefinition;
            bodyDefinition.type = b2_dynamicBody;
            bodyDefinition.position.Set(96/PTM_RATIO, 96/PTM_RATIO);
            bodyDefinition.userData = sprite;

            obstacle_AdjustmentsBody= world->CreateBody(&bodyDefinition);

            // Create body shape
            b2PolygonShape bodyShape;
            //row 1, col 1
            int num = 4;
            b2Vec2 verts[] = {
                b2Vec2(108.0f / PTM_RATIO, -71.5f / PTM_RATIO),
                b2Vec2(56.0f / PTM_RATIO, 2.5f / PTM_RATIO),
                b2Vec2(47.0f / PTM_RATIO, -3.5f / PTM_RATIO),
                b2Vec2(96.0f / PTM_RATIO, -75.5f / PTM_RATIO)
            };

            bodyShape.Set(verts, num);

            // Create shape definition and add to body
            b2FixtureDef bodyFixtureDefinition;
            bodyFixtureDefinition.shape = &bodyShape;
            bodyFixtureDefinition.density = 100.0f;
            bodyFixtureDefinition.friction = 0.01f;
            bodyFixtureDefinition.restitution = 0.50f;              
            obstacle_AdjustmentsFixture=obstacle_AdjustmentsBody->CreateFixture(&bodyFixtureDefinition);            
        }

        //SHAPE SECOND LEG OF X:
        {
            b2BodyDef bodyDefinition;
            bodyDefinition.type = b2_dynamicBody;
            bodyDefinition.position.Set(96/PTM_RATIO, 96/PTM_RATIO);
            bodyDefinition.userData = sprite;

            obstacle_AdjustmentsBody= world->CreateBody(&bodyDefinition);

            // Create body shape
            b2PolygonShape bodyShape;
            //row 1, col 1
            int num = 4;
            b2Vec2 verts[] = {
                b2Vec2(117.0f / PTM_RATIO, -4.5f / PTM_RATIO),
                b2Vec2(113.0f / PTM_RATIO, -1.5f / PTM_RATIO),
                b2Vec2(54.0f / PTM_RATIO, -51.5f / PTM_RATIO),
                b2Vec2(61.0f / PTM_RATIO, -56.5f / PTM_RATIO)
            };

            bodyShape.Set(verts, num);

            // Create shape definition and add to body
            b2FixtureDef bodyFixtureDefinition;
            bodyFixtureDefinition.shape = &bodyShape;
            bodyFixtureDefinition.density = 100.0f;
            bodyFixtureDefinition.friction = 0.01f;
            bodyFixtureDefinition.restitution = 0.50f;              
            obstacle_AdjustmentsFixture=obstacle_AdjustmentsBody->CreateFixture(&bodyFixtureDefinition);            
        }
}
```

Comment: Oh YES this will work for any kind of any shape. just use vertexHelper to define the shape.

Comment: Thanks! I see `X` is broken into two legs. What happens to continuous concave shape, say `C`, does vertexHelper handle this well?

Comment: Ammmm, not soo accurately, but You can shape it like SIX segment display.

Comment: Refer [THIS](http://www.springenwerk.com/2010/02/introducing-vertexhelper-for-box2d.html) Link for knowing more about Vertext Helper